# Playframework 2 include a updatable combobox in a list (not a form)

Tags: list, combobox, twitter-bootstrap, onclick, playframework-2.0

I am using play framework 2.0 .I a page where I list all the elements that the user can edit/delete. one of the listed elements in a look up from another table. I have coded a select in the forms and that works fine.

I would like to include the combo box in the displayed list, so the user can update it right there without having to drill down into each element to update the field. Is there a way to do this? I want to listen to the change in the combobox and update the underlying model.

I tried a few iterations, but the select box seems to want a play.api.data.Field , and not the value I provide.

the parameters to the page is a pageable list like this 
@(currentPage: Page[Deal], currentSortBy: String, currentOrder: String, currentFilter: String)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand the issue, but I think the problem you are stating would be better solved at the client, with some ajax in it...

otherwise, you would be issuing a whole page refresh every time the user updates the items

I would expose the pageable list like a rest-json web service, and I wuld call it from javascript, binding the on-change event...

Here you have an example using select2 to do the lookup and consumign a rest web service: http://bb-jugar.rhcloud.com/assets/js/tmp/select2/demo.html